# Finding a system vulnerable to dirtycow

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, ubuntu-10.04, linux-kernel

I'm not sure where to turn, so I turned to this forum. Please don't downvote me for nothing, I'm just trying to ask a question.

Hello! So, I've been trying to find a system vulnerable to dirtycow and I can't find any. (atleast any that can compile C code...)

### Things I tried

- Using the dirtycow PoC on ubuntu 10 LTS, ubuntu 9 LTS and it didn't work. ( View my previous question)
- Installing debian 7 or debian 6, but they don't have gcc installed in them.

So my question is

> which .iso can I install in order to try out dirtycow? (I'm writing an article so I want to test it for myself)

**NOTE:** I've tested the kernel versions of all the things I've tested, and they seemed vulnerable. so I'm not sure. I ran all the virtual machines in virtualbox / vmware with 3 cores and a lot of RAM and HDD memory.

Comment: Linux releases that were still actively maintained when the a vulnerability was discovered, will most likely ship with patched kernel that fixes the issue. In general the trick to test vulnerabilities in a particular Linux kernel version is to download  a vulnerable release of the Linux kernel source to build and install your own  kernel. Then reboot your  system to that the vulnerable kernel version